# Audio buffer finite error after butter filtering (Scipy)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signal-processing

I have an audio signal which I pass through a `butter` bandpass filter:

```
def bandpass_filter(y, sr, lowcut, highcut):
  # Setup parameters.
  nyquist_rate = sr / 2.
  filter_order = 1001
  normalized_low = lowcut / nyquist_rate
  normalized_high = highcut / nyquist_rate

  b, a = butter(filter_order, [normalized_low, normalized_high], btype='bandpass')

  y = lfilter(b, a, y)
  return y
```

I then use this returned, filtered signal to detect some pitches using a library called [Librosa](http://librosa.github.io/librosa/).

When I call:

```
  pitches, magnitudes = librosa.piptrack(y=y, sr=sr, fmin=fmin, fmax=fmax)
```

Where `y` is the filtered audio signal, I get this error:

```
librosa.util.exceptions.ParameterError
ParameterError: Audio buffer is not finite everywhere
```

Which basically comes from this check:

```
if not np.isfinite(y).all():
    raise ParameterError('Audio buffer is not finite everywhere')
```

Why did this happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are attempting to create a [Butterworth filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterworth_filter) (which is an [IIR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_impulse_response) filter) with order 1001, represented using the transfer function coefficients (b, a).  The transfer function is a rational function, which is the ratio of two polynomials, and the evaluation of high order polynomials is very susceptible to numerical error.  What you are trying to do is doomed to fail.

Some suggestions:

- Rethink the need for a filter with order 1001.  Why are you trying to create a filter with such a high order?
- You'll get better numerical behavior if you use the SOS (second order sections) format for the filter, instead of the transfer function (b, a).

Try using a *much* lower order, and try using [`scipy.signal.sosfilt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.sosfilt.html) to filter the signal:

```
sos = butter(filter_order, [normalized_low, normalized_high], btype='bandpass', output='sos')
y = sosfilt(sos, y)
```